# Where created files go?

Tags: android

I'm creating a file world-readable using this instruction:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename.toString(), MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

file is created (i can see emulator's memory and file is there), but I can't find it on my device!!
Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Application's Internal Storage**.. by default `/data/data/<package_name>/`

Check this directory..

But if your device is non-rooted then you can not seen this file in **DDMS -> FIle-Explorer**.

For this you can try via commnad prompt using `adb shell`

If you want to just access files in your application then use,

```
getFilesDir()
```

**Gets the absolute path to the filesystem directory where your internal files are saved.**

Comment: For more information look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: What I'd really want is to allow phone's user to see this file..so my only option would be to save it to sdcard?

Comment: Also there are some File Manager applications can also see the files from Application Internal Storage.

Comment: Actually, Application Internal Storage is used for a files which are used for Application through only. For other use you can try External Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The file is located in /data/data/com.yourpackagename/files/filename.txt which is hidden unless the device is rooted. You can access the file by copying it from the directory where it is created.

From the command line:

To copy a file

```
adb -d shell 
run-as com.yourpackagename 
cat /data/data/com.yourpackagename/files/filename.txt > /sdcard/filename.txt
```

Alternatively for a SQLite database

```
cat /data/data/com.yourpackagename/databases/dbname.db > /sdcard/dbname.sqlite
```

This solution will work without having to root the device.